# Trying to get the total count in core data store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record along with my core data model, and I am basically trying to count all of the entities in my store so that I can display them in a UILabel; however, for some reason the label is only displaying 2 entries when in facts there are multiple. Every time that I create a new one it basically doesn't update the UILabel. Here's my code:

```
NSNumber *count = [FinalRead MR_numberOfEntities];

    self.numberInbox = count;
    NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inbox(%@)", self.numberInbox];
    inboxLabel.text = formattedNumber;
    inboxLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    inboxLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    inboxLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    inboxLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
```

Now i must have done something right in the first place otherwise a number would not have displayed, so there must be something I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Comment: What code is updating the label when the model content changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update the text of inboxLabel (and your state variable numberInbox) whenever you create a new entity.  The NSString you assign to inboxLabel.text will not update automatically – it will always show the count from when your sample code is run (nor will numberInbox update automatically).

Update your state variable and the inboxLabel text immediately after your code that creates a new entity:

```
self.numberInbox = [FinalRead MR_numberOfEntities];
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inbox(%@)", self.numberInbox];
inboxLabel.text = formattedNumber;
```

(If entities can be deleted, call this after your deletion code, too.)

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't even thought of that to be honest. Thanks for the help, Teddy!